# How do I customize date/time formats in Kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04

In all prior versions of Kubuntu I've ever used (going back five years or so), I can go to System Settings and customize the date/time formats, specifying that I want 24-hour time, short dates, whatever.  In 15.04, apparently, all you can do is pick a country and it uses the locale settings for that country.  This is absurd, to say the least.  Why were these settings removed?

I don't know if this is also the case in regular Ubuntu (I strongly dislike Unity), but I sure as heck hope there's some way to get this functionality back.  Being forced to use 12-hour time simply because my locale is the US is ridiculous.  I can change my Time setting to "United Kingdom", which solves the time problem, but then sets a Date setting that I absolutely don't want to use.

Whose idea was this, and where can I find them to complain?

Comment: You are using KDE - the KDE has own forum: https://forum.kde.org . A pick: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=124741 . A KDE bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345378#c8 . A workaround to format the time/clock: http://askubuntu.com/questions/611240/kde-clock-format-how-to-include-the-day-in-a-non-tiny-font/611814

Comment: Does not it have the option to select 12/24 hour format in the time and date settings ? in my 14.04 its in the `Clock` tab of `Time and Date` ..also please remove your answer..if you something to add please edit your question and add that..

Comment: @heemayl - 14.04 and 15.04 are very different, and 15.04 does not let you customize date/time formats beyond picking a locale.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the clock and choose the "settings for digital clock" then customize it to your willings and press the apply button.

Answer (score 0):

Since Plasma 5.4:

1. Right-click on digital clock
2. Select "Digital Clock Settings"
3. Check "Use 24 hour clock" (about half-way down the dialog)